# Difficulty creating Fixture for FitNesse CSlim

Tags: testing, automation, fitnesse, acceptance

I have recently started working with FitNesse and am trying to create Acceptance Tests for C++ code through it. I have recently downloaded CSlim and seem to be unable to get the example fixtures to work. Here is a copy of the fixture code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SlimList.h"
#include "Fixtures.h"

class cMultiplication 
{
    public:
    cMultiplication(){};
    ~cMultiplication(){};
    float product()
    {
        return m1*m2;
    }
    float m1;
    float m2;
    char result[32];    
};

#ifndef CPP_COMPILING
extern "C" {
#endif
typedef struct Multiplication
{
    cMultiplication multiplication;
    char result[32];
} Multiplication;

void* Multiplication_Create(StatementExecutor* errorHandler, SlimList* args)
{
    Multiplication* self = (Multiplication*)malloc(sizeof(Multiplication));
    self->result[0] = 0;
     // self->multiplication = new cMultiplication();
    return self;
}

void Multiplication_Destroy(void* void_self)
{
    Multiplication* self = (Multiplication*)void_self;
    // delete self->multiplication;
    free(self);
}

static char* setMultiplicand1(void* void_self, SlimList* args) {
    Multiplication* self = (Multiplication*)void_self;
    self->multiplication.m1 = atof(SlimList_GetStringAt(args, 0));
    return self->result;
}

static char* setMultiplicand2(void* void_self, SlimList* args) {
    Multiplication* self = (Multiplication*)void_self;
    self->multiplication.m2 = atof(SlimList_GetStringAt(args, 0));
    return self->result;
}

static char* Product(void* void_self, SlimList* args) {
    Multiplication* self = (Multiplication*)void_self;
    float product = self->multiplication.product();
    snprintf(self->result, 32, "%g", product);
    return self->result;
}


SLIM_CREATE_FIXTURE(Multiplication) 
    SLIM_FUNCTION(setMultiplicand1)
    SLIM_FUNCTION(setMultiplicand2)
    SLIM_FUNCTION(Product)
SLIM_END

#ifndef CPP_COMPILING
}
#endif
```

I would appreicate any help and wisdom that you have to give me.

```
<code>!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

!path C:\Users\212411176\Documents\Git_Repositories\cslim-master\fixtures\

!define COLLAPSE_SETUP {true}
!define COLLAPSE_TEARDOWN {true}


!|import|
|FixtureInCpp.cpp|

|cMultiplication|
|Multiplication1|Multiplication2|Product?|
|1|1|1|
|5|4|20|
|5|4|20|
```

Thanks In Advance for any insight you can give me.

Cheers,

Alexander

Comment: I am under the impression that I have not selected the correct runner for CSlim. Unfortunately I have been unable to find the runner anywhere in the zip folder I pulled off of the [CSlim GitHub project](https://github.com/dougbradbury/cslim/tree/master/src/CSlim). Does anyone know where to get the runner for CSlim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fixture needs to be updated, try following fixture

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim} 
!define TEST_RUNNER {PATH_TO_CSlim}
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m} 
!define SLIM_VERSION {0.0} 

!|import|
|FixtureInCpp.cpp|
```

`|Multiplication|`
    |Multiplicand1|Multiplicand2|Product?|
`|1|1|1|`
    `|5|4|20|`
    `|5|4|20|`